# Converting flux column timedate to posixct for hour rounding: error convert class to POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

**I need to round a date time column in flux data to the nearest hour in R, but when I use asPOSIXct I get the response**

> Error in as.POSIXct.default(flux_dt10, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS") :
> do not know how to convert 'flux_dt10' to class “POSIXct”

The dataset is a column of values like:

```
flux_dt10 <- "01APR2019:11:51:42"
```

I have tried:

```
as.POSIXct(flux_dt10,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
```

but gives the response not knowing how to convert data to class "POSIXct".

Answer (score 2):

**1) Base R** Ensure that the format string corresponds to the actual format of the input and then use round.  ?strptime gives the meanings of the percent codes.

```
round(as.POSIXct("01APR2019:11:51:42", format = "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"), units = "hours")
## [1] "2019-04-01 12:00:00 EDT"
```

**2) anytime** or the anytime package can figure out the format on its own without a format string in this case:

```
library(anytime)

round(anytime("01APR2019:11:51:42"), units = "hours")
## [1] "2019-04-01 12:00:00 EDT"
```

**3) lubridate** It can also be done using the lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)

round_date(dmy_hms("01APR2019:11:51:42", tz = ""), unit = "hour")
## [1] "2019-04-01 12:00:00 EDT"
```